# Has anyone succesfully used a background job gem under Windows, using Rails 3?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, background-process

I have been trying to use `delayed_job` for about 1 hour on Windows with no success. Before going off and trying the next candidates, I decided it could be wiser to ask for other experiences of background job processing under Windows. Has anyone used something succesfully with Rails 3?

EDIT: to win the bounty, please list, if any, gems for starting background jobs that work under Windows.

Comment: Most solutions are not going to work because they utilize `fork`, which is for *nix. Are you stuck using Windows? You might look into Win32Utils' win-process, but you might have to create something yourself with it. http://rubyforge.org/docman/view.php/85/1720/Process.html

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to use Windows.

Comment: There's this, but it looks pretty old (the latest version was released in 2008): https://github.com/ahoward/bj. There are a few forks though, maybe you'll find one that make you happy.

Comment: Looking through the forks, I can see https://github.com/SciMed/bj which claims support for windows. Add it as an answer and I will mark it :)

Comment: I have been successfully using `delayed_job` on Windows, using Rails 3.0.9 and Ruby 1.9.2.
I just type rake jobs:work and off it goes. What problems are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the [Backgroundjob gem](https://github.com/ahoward/bj), but it looks pretty old (the latest version was released in 2008). It should support windows, here's the quote from the README:

> platform independent (including winblows [sic])

There are a few forks though, maybe you will find one that you can use without much pain.